# How do you mark a single container as a dropDestination for multiple Transferable types?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm using the new Transferable protocol with the draggable/dropDestination modifiers to let users drop content onto a ZStack. The issue I'm having is that I want to support multiple Transferable types being dropped into a single container. For example, I want users to be able to drop a String, a URL, or a Data (i.e., image data) onto a single ZStack. The problem is that the "for" parameter on the dropDestination view modifier does not accept multiple Types, like the onDrop modifier does.

I tried adding a second dropDestination modifier with a different payload, but when I drop an item corresponding to the second drop destination payload, I see an icon on the dragged image that indicates dropping is not allowed. However, if I drop a String payload, I get the + icon as I would expect, and the drop is successful.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var stringPayload: String = ""
    @State private var urlPayload: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow
                Text(stringPayload)
                if let urlPayload {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: (try? Data(contentsOf: urlPayload))!)!)
                }
            }
            .dropDestination(for: String.self) { items, location in
                stringPayload = items.first!
                return true
            }
            .dropDestination(for: URL.self) { items, location in
                return true
            }
            Text("Hello world!")
                .draggable("Hello world!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Raise a ticket with Apple TSI (DTS team) and see if they can help, if it is a limitation, could you file a feedback, thanks.

Comment: @user1046037 Thanks for the suggestion. I went ahead and filed a feedback. I'll update here, if I ever hear back from Apple.

Comment: One possible workaround I discovered was I could put a separate dropDestination on another container, as long as the other container does not overlap with the first one. It's almost as if the drop capability can't see through multiple levels of drop containers. This isn't ideal, because now the user has to know the type of data they are dropping and then drop them onto the appropriate visual container.

Comment: Glad you filed the feedback, hopefully it gets addressed, but might take a while, so don't wait on it, so any workaround UI you can think of is better. `Transferable` is much nicer than `NSItemProvider` and I feel `Transferable` would be the future but may take some time to catch up.

Comment: It is not ideal but see if `ProxyRepresentation` helps you, using it URL could fall back to a string. That way both URL and String could be be dropped on the same view. Refer [Meet Transferable](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10062)

Comment: @user1046037 Thanks for the suggestion. I'll take a look at `ProxyRepresentation`... if it can fall back to String, that just might work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to @user1046037's suggestion to look at ProxyRepresentation, I was able to put together some code that allows me to accept multiple drop types within a single dropDestination receiver.

First, I created a separate enum to represent the different types of data that could be dropped:

```
import CoreTransferable

enum DropItem: Codable, Transferable {
    case none
    case text(String)
    case url(URL)
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        ProxyRepresentation { DropItem.text($0) }
        ProxyRepresentation { DropItem.url($0) }
    }
    
    var text: String? {
        switch self {
            case .text(let str): return str
            default: return nil
        }
    }
    
    var url: URL? {
        switch self {
            case.url(let url): return url
            default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the View, just tell the dropDestination to accept items of type DropItem.self, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var payload: DropItem = .none
    @State private var urlPayload: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow
                if let text = payload.text {
                    Text(text)
                } else if let url = payload.url {
                    Text(url.absoluteString)
                }
            }
            .dropDestination(for: DropItem.self) { items, location in
                payload = items.first!
                return true
            }
            Text("Hello world!")
                .draggable("Hello world!")
        }
    }
}
```

What's really nice about this approach is that you can rely on strongly typed DropItems to determine what to do based on the case in the enum that is received.